# Calculate db.DaysPastDue from DateTime.Now - db.Loan.DueDate in Controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to calculate the `daysPastDue` in my application which will be calculated by `DateTime.Now - Loan.DueDate`.

An example would be: 
`Loan.DueDate` = 2/1/18 12:00:00
`DateTime.Now` = 2/4/18 2:17:00
`DaysPastDue` = Should be '3'

I can do this from my view by doing the following:

**View**

```
@if (DateTime.Now > item.Loan.DueDate)
{    
     item.Loan.DaysPastDue = (DateTime.Now - item.Loan.DueDate).Value.Days;
}
```

But the problem here is that it never saves in my database it just calculates on the view.

So I wanted to calculate the `Loan.DaysPastDue` value and do a `db.SaveChanges()` before I display the view.

How do I accomplish this?

**Edit:**
Here is my update/insert method:

```
    // GET: Kits
            [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var kits = db.Kits.Include(k => k.Loan).Include(k => k.Products); 

//Right here is where I wanted to do something like:
// if (DateTime.Now > db.Loan.DueDate)
//{
//      var daysPastDue = (DateTime.Now - item.Loan.DueDate).Value.Days;
//      Loan.DaysPastDue = daysPastDue;
//      db.SaveChanges(Loan.DaysPastDue) //This is the part I think I'm stuck on            
   return View(kits.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Show us your update/insert method.

Comment: Just added.  However, you will notice I'm trying to save the DaysPastDue value in my KitController which has a .Include to my LoanController.  The reason I am doing this in my KitController is because LoanController/Index is never viewed by the user but I still want to update the DaysPastDue value.

Comment: If you only care about whole days, then you might consider changing your `if` condition to ignore smaller differences (like hours, minutes, etc): `if (DateTime.Today > item.Loan.DueDate.Date)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually don't want to save a calculated value in the database. In your sample, it's 3 days past due now. Tomorrow it's 4 days. The view will show 4 days because it's calculating it, but how will the database value get updated if someone doesn't pull up that view?

If you still want to recompute and save that value when the view is shown, something like this should work:

```
foreach(var kit in kits.Where(k => DateTime.Now > k.Loan.DueDate)
{
    kit.Loan.DaysPastDue = (DateTime.Now - kit.Loan.DueDate).Value.Days;
    db.SaveChanges(kit);
}
```

Comment: "how will the database value get updated if someone doesn't pull up that view" -- Very valid question, however in this case I really don't care about this date unless the user pulls up this view and in this case this view is set as the default load page as the default route.  But this should get me closer to what I need to do. Thanks.